# PHP line breaks being messed up by GIT

Tags: php, git, newline

Our website has one section which often changes to match the user. (examples are greatly simplified).

```
user:Mike
last visit:Yesterday
```

The method used to update the content [which I cannot now change] is that php searches the html webpage for the default content, and replaces it with new content before serving it to the user.

```
$stats = "user:Mike
last visit:Yesterday";
$defaults = "user:Guest
last visit:None";
$code = implode($stats, explode($defaults, $code));
```

All was fine till we started backing up the site with GIT [a glutton for punishment, we are].

It seems that GIT changes the newline character in the html page, and therefore php can no longer find the original text.

I do not understand how newlines are stored or changed, but occasionally I get an error from GIT during the submit, saying it must change the newline, and offering 'unlock' or 'continue'.

This is followed by the site not working, till I copy/paste the default text from an externally stored copy into that page - and don't do a commit.

I am aware that I can use regex to make the search/replace but the page sees enough usage for me to avoid unneeded expressions.

My local machine runs Windows.  The server runs Unix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html

> **crlf**
>
> This attribute controls the
>   line-ending convention.
>
> *Set* Setting the crlf attribute on a
>   path is meant to mark the path as a
>   "text" file. core.autocrlf conversion
>   takes place without guessing the
>   content type by inspection.
>
> *Unset* Unsetting the crlf attribute on
>   a path tells git not to attempt any
>   end-of-line conversion upon checkin or
>   checkout.

Tell git not to convert CRLFs by specifying `crlf` as `Unset` for the files in question and the issue should go away.

Comment: Please help me understand how to do this?

Comment: http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html should give you a slightly more user-friendly overview of how gitattributes files work. But specifically, what you'd want to do is go into the directory with the files that shouldn't be CRLF-converted, and create a file there named `.gitattributes` with the line `*.html -crlf` as its contents. This will stop git from converting CRLFs for any .html files within that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you don't have `core.autocrlf` set to "input" (e.g. using "`git config --get core.autocrlf`").

This configuration variable makes Git convert MS Windows end-of-line convention "\r\n" (CRLF) to UNIX convention "\n" (LF).  See [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) manpage for details; the `crlf` gitattribute that [Dav mentioned in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361795/php-line-breaks-being-messed-up-by-git/1361848#1361848) is to have more fine-tuned selection.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's converting Windows newlines (`\r\n`, or `0x0D0A`) to Unix newlines (`\n`, or 0x0A). If your HTML contains Windows line endings, searching for a Unix-style line ending in the middle of a string won't work. You can explicitly state which one you want like this:

```
$stats = "user:Mike\r\nlast visit:Yesterday";
```

Or:

```
$stats = "user:Mike\nlast visit:Yesterday";
```

Comment: The actual content is very long and complex, and I can't replace the spaces [which the human designers require] with \r\n.
If there is a way to have \r\n as well as the new line that shows up in the editor, that would be fine - can that be done?  For the record, before switching to GIT it was no problem even though my machine is a Windows box.

Comment: Is there a difference between the 'continue' and 'unlock' options when GIT throws the newline error?

Comment: I'm not a Git user, so I couldn't say. It seems Dav has the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

During install, mysGit gives the option of leaving line-breaks as they are.

This solved the problem once I upgraded.